# How can we create a data array for google map markers using data from asp.net mvc model?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I want to create a data array in JavaScript for google map markers using data from asp.net mvc model and wrote this snippet

```
 var locations = [];
@foreach (var d in Model.Properties.Where(p=>p.Longitude!=null))
{
@:locations.push("@d.Description", "@d.Latitude", "@d.Longitude",@d.Id);
}
```

But I am not getting the expected results, as there is a problem with the data array which I want to be like this one bellow

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Comment: What results _are_ you getting?

Comment: I don't know asp.net but shouldn't is just be `@:locations.push(@d.Description, @d.Latitude, @d.Longitude,@d.Id);`?

Comment: @Andy I  logged "locations[i][1]" instead of getting the  latitude i am getting a single character

Comment: @AsimJavaid can't you add the results of `console.log(Model.Properties.Where(p=>p.Longitude!=null), locations );` after the foreach loop in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@:locations.push("@d.Description", "@d.Latitude", "@d.Longitude",@d.Id);
```

defining it as

```
@:locations.push(["@d.Description", "@d.Latitude", "@d.Longitude",@d.Id]);
```

Solved the issue.